# Add content before and after a class - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How do I add a div starter "`<div class='abc'>`" to
`<img src="bla.jpg" class="xyz"/>` and end it with "`</div>`"
So that the DOM will be:

```
<div class='abc'>
   <img src="bla.jpg" class="xyz"/>
</div>
```

I tried using this jQuery code:

```
$('img.xyz').before("<div class='abc'>").after("</div>");
```

But it gives me the DOM as:

```
<div class='abc'></div>
<img src="bla.jpg" class="xyz"/>
```

Comment: As the answers suggest, `.wrap()` is the way to go... the reason your code doesn't work is because `.before()` returns the div jQuery object, therefore `.after()` adds after that, not the image.

Comment: @Ben: That's not actually right. The `.before()` method returns the `img` jQuery object, but the `after()` was attempting to insert a closing `</div>` tag, which just doesn't work.

Comment: @Patrick... oh dear, I stand corrected :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('img.xyz').wrap('<div class="abc" />');
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap

Answer (score 2):

Use the .wrap() method:

```
$('img.xyz').wrap('<div class="abc" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wrap` method:

```
$('img.xyz').wrap('<div class="abc"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

use **jQuery wrap()** to achieve your goal:

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/